# spring data flow bind source app to multiple named destinations

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying out spring data flow to see if it fits my needs. I am wondering how can I bind my spring cloud stream app to multiple named destinations (in my case RabbitMQ exchanges). From what I have read, you can bind multiple apps to one named destination (fan in/out) but not one app to multiple destinations...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input/output.destination` property allows you to specify the name(s) of the destinations. NOTE: that "input" or "output" in the above corresponds to the channel name of your message handler (e.g., `@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)`)
Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: No, I know that you can do it on app level, but I wanted to see if it's possible on data-flow level (in dsl flow).

Comment: That is just an application property, so yes